# Manual Average in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Why is there difference when i use mean() function for a image matrix and when i do that manually?
see :

```
im=imread('img.jpg');
imshow(uint8(mean(im,3)));
figure;
imshow(uint8((im(:,:,1)+im(:,:,2)+im(:,:,3))/3));
```

Comment: Are you sure that the manual mean doesn't saturate uint8 values?

Comment: `im(:,:,1)+im(:,:,2)+im(:,:,3)` clips off value at 255. So, the custom method doesn't quite work as you wish. Convert to double and then divide by 3. If using `im2double` for that, scale up by 255 before dividing by 3.